# file_get_contents returns failed to open stream: Connection timed out error

Tags: php, bash, curl, file-get-contents

I was using the following code on my Centos machine to fetch URL response:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

It returns the error:

> "Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in testFGC.php on line 3"

I've checked the `php.ini` file. Everything looks fine. `iptables` and `ip6tables` are off.

I've tried using `curl` instead of `file_get_contents`, but that doesn't work as well.

But a normal curl on the bash command line works absolutely fine(returns the html content).

```
curl www.google.com
```

What can be the reason? Can Firewall rules be the problem even though the bash curl is working? Thank you.

Comment: Try another website, It will work..

Comment: Wasn't working for any external websites. Was working for all local network IPs.

Comment: you say that curl don't work, well then enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the curl verbose log. `$ch=curl_init();$tmp=tmpfile();curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$tmp,CURLOPT_URL=>'http://google.com'));curl_exec($ch);/*php bug 76268 workaround*/rewind($tmp);var_dump(stream_get_contents($tmp));curl_close($ch);fclose($tmp);`, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like its actually a problem with your server, not your code. However, if you say that curl works, you can use curl in your code

```
$curl = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$html = curl_exec($curl);
//html var will contain the html code 

if (curl_error($curl)){
    die(curl_error($curl));
}
// Check for HTTP Codes (if you want)
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, that **`file_get_contents`** does not get a response from the host www.google.com

Otherwise yout code is pefect for getting host content,

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
    echo $homepage;
?>
```

#### I test on here.... <kbd>**[CodeViper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qAX26C)**</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, but why am I not getting a response?

Comment: are you try to get content from other any website

Comment: Wasn't able to get any content from any website outside the network. Was working fine for local VMs